# php: execute query with PDO OCI

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I'm trying execute simple script, but can't get result.

```
$id = $_GET['contract'];
$dsn = 'oci:dbname=xxx.xxx.xx';
$user = 'xxxx';
$pass = 'xxxx';

try{
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM DOGOVOR.CONTRACT CTR WHERE CTR.CONTRACTORNUMDOC = ?');
    $stmt->execute(array($id));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

var_dump($row);
```

result - bool(false). None errors.
If i try query only "SELECT * FROM DOGOVOR.CONTRACT", then all ok. Need to say that $id take cyrilic value. May it be problem with charset or something else?
Oracle 9i. PHP 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT CTR.* FROM DOGOVOR.CONTRACT CTR WHERE CTR.CONTRACTORNUMDOC = ?
```

Here you missed `CTR.*`

or simpler:

```
SELECT * FROM DOGOVOR.CONTRACT WHERE CONTRACTORNUMDOC = ?
```

Comment: are you sure that record with `CONTRACTORNUMDOC = $id` exists?

Comment: get strange behavior for me. If i get /index.php?contract=ИД-2007-ФКс0-218 then i get bool(false) result. If i write $id = 'ИД-2007-ФКс0-218' in code, then i get result from base.

Comment: @user837758: strange, I don't have any idea :(

Comment: 100% problem with charset, because if i echo 2 value: from $_GET and inner $id i get difference value in different charset

Comment: problem with charset. iconv helped me.